# Datagridview - Datasource - Argument Out of Range Exception

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, datagridview

My first question on SO, I 've been coding 3 months: I am binding a custom object to a datagridview.  The object is filled from an async task.  Last night it was working fine, today it comes up with an AOR exception.

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
dataGridView2.Refresh();
dataGridView2.DataSource = process_action_table;
```

This is my first of a heap of problems.
The process action table has entries, as shown in the debugger, so on this occassion, had been correctly filled.
Why oh why, would I get an exception on the dgv step, when this has worked reliably before?  I realise you may need more info, any help or feedback would be appreciated.

```
public void PulldtUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch(); PullMoment4(marketidlist);
sw.Reset(); 
sw.Start(); 
dataGridView2.DataSource = null; 
dataGridView2.Refresh();     
dataGridView2.DataSource = dtAll; 
sw.Stop(); textBox1.SelectionStart =textBox1.Text.Length;
textBox1.ScrollToCaret(); 
label7.Text = cycle_time; 
label10.Text =     sw.Elapsed.ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: Can you add more code? Have you on this part a try/catch block? Have you other events on the datagridview?

Comment: I don't have it on a try catch block..  public void PulldtUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();        PullMoment4(marketidlist);
             sw.Reset();           sw.Start();           dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
           dataGridView2.Refresh();
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dtAll;            sw.Stop();
            textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
            textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
            label7.Text = cycle_time;
            label10.Text = sw.Elapsed.ToString();        
        }

Comment: er..that was suppossed to be a block of code

Comment: Update your original question is not readable as comment :)

Comment: How you call this method PulldtUpdate?

Comment: Hi folks, problem solved for now.  I changed this line: dataGridView2.DataSource = null; to = typeof<DataTable>     as per another SO's suggestion.  This has fixed it for me.  THank ypou for youer help folks, and next time I'll try to ask the question better.